# 'InvalidRegistration' FCM when sending Push Notifications via Appium and Python

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, appium

I'm getting 'InvalidRegistration' error when I try to send a push notification to my Android device.

Header:

```
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=' + serverToken,
{
```

Body:

```
    body = {
        "to": deviceToken,
        "notification": {
            "body": "Welcome to blabla",
            "title": "Blabla trully loves you, did you know that?",
            "priority": "high"
        }
```

Response:

```
    200
    {'multicast_id': 6053848281333651847, 'success': 0, 'failure': 1, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'results': [{'error': 'NotRegistered'}]}
```

The idea is that I'm using Appium method ***driver.get_clipboard_text()*** to get a token which is already copied in device clipboard and store it in the following variable:

```
deviceToken = self.driver.get_clipboard_text()
```

Which I pass it to my JSON. Also, if I manually store the token in my variable it will successfully work and get the push notification on my device.

I've tried to use several formatting python types by using another variable where i store a previous one where I do call that method I mentioned from Appium, but without success.

Any thoughts?